# How to insert value to muliple column from textarea use PHP?

Tags: sql, insert, textarea

I want to insert value to multiple database from Textarea, example i enter value to textarea and submit :

```
1|Vo Huu Nhan 1
2|Vo huu Nhan 2
3|Vo Huu Nhan 3
```

After submit i want insert value before "|" to column `tap` and value after "|" to column `player`
My code :

```
<form action="Post.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="tapphim"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/></form>
```

Please help me create Post.php file right way

Answer (score 0):

Firstly which programming language are you using?
For all programming languages, the concept is similar.
Take the input text from the textarea , then explode the '|' out of it ....then it becomes an array .
After that insert the first value of the array into the tap column then the other one into the players column.

The expression might look like this:
`array[0] into tap column,
array[1] into players column`

But i will like to know the programming language you want to use in achieving this
I hope it enlightens you.

Since you are using php

```
`if(isset($_POST['tapphim']) && !empty($_POST['tapphim'])
 {
     $textAreaInput = explode("|", $_POST['tapphim']);
      $tapValue = $textAreaInput[0];
       $playerName = $textAreaInput[1];
        $sql = mysqli_query($con,"insert into 
      playersTble(tap,players) 
       values('$textAreaInput','$playerName");
       if($sql){
           echo "data saved!";
       }
}`
```

i Hope this solves your problem.
Make sure you read about sanitizing input in PHP

Comment: I use PHP language

Comment: You are welcome, kindly select it as accepted answer if it solves your problem. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(isset($_POST['tapphim'])){

    $lineSplit=explode("\n", $_POST['tapphim']);

    foreach ($lineSplit as $line) {

        $splitArr=explode("|", $line);

        $fieldOne=$splitArr[0];
        $fieldTwo=$splitArr[1];

        // insert to db 
    }
}
```

You may want to use `htmlspecialchars($_POST['tapphim'])` or `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tapphim'])` to clear post variables from dangerous characters for security reasons especially if you don't use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) connection to connect your database.

Comment: I edited my post, please help me create Post.php file